# Linux awk command

Tags: awk

I am a beginner in using Linux, I have an input file with content like:

```
00.11.11.11.11.11
177.22.22.22
```

one line of Ethernet address and one line of IP address,
how can I convert this file to:

```
IP: 177.22.22.22  MAC: 00.11.11.11.11.11
```

I think awk would do it, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done with 'sed', too, but since you ask for 'awk', 'awk' it shall be.

```
awk '/^([0-9]+\.){5}[0-9]+$/ { mac = $1 }
     /^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$/ { printf "IP: %s MAC: %s\n", $1, mac }' data
```

(Previous version:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ { mac = $1 }
     /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ { printf "IP: %s MAC: %s\n", $1, mac }'
```

Not so good because of the written out repeat, instead of counted repeat.)

The first line matches MAC addresses and saves the most recent in variable mac.  The second matches IP (IPv4) addresses and prints the current MAC address and IP address.

If you have stray leading or trailing blanks, or other stray characters, you need to make the regexes appropriately more complicated.

Comment: Yikes!  @Jason, maybe you can put the IP and MAC on the same line with whitespace in between and `cat file | awk '{print "IP:", $1, "MAC:", $2}'` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Note that this skips blank lines or lines which don't match precisely 4 or 6 dotted decimal numbers - which may or may not be a virtue.  The same MAC address could be used for a number of IP addresses, for example, if the data was not strictly alternating lines.  Other solutions that do not scrutinize the input data are vulnerable to getting out of sync with the data - if the data is malformed.

Answer (score 3):

You can  **[try it at ideone:](http://ideone.com/gmdiy)**

Really short!

```
{mac=$0;
 getline ip;
 print "IP: " ip  " MAC: " mac}
```

Answer (score 3):

`paste - - < input_file | awk '{print "IP: " $2 " MAC: " $1}'`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance ... Does "paste - -" turn every two lines into one?

Comment: paste turns its input into columns, the number of columns is the '- -'

Comment: nice! +1 // 7 more chars to go go

Answer (score 2):

awk -vRS= '{print "IP:", $2, "MAC:", $1;}'

which is equivalent to

awk 'BEGIN{RS="";}{print "IP:", $2, "MAC:", $1;}'

This works also with multiple input records:
"
00.11.22.33.44.55
123.45.67.89

11.22.33.44.55.66
11.22.33.99
"

->

"
IP: 123.45.67.89 MAC: 00.11.22.33.44.55
IP: 11.22.33.99 MAC: 11.22.33.44.55.66
"

Comment: That requires blank lines separating the pairs of data lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ if(mac) { print "IP:", $0, "MAC:", mac; mac = 0 } else mac = $0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` version for variety:

```
sed 's/^/MAC: /;x;N;s/\n/IP: /;G;s/\n/  /' inputfile
```

If there is more than one pair of lines in the file:

```
sed 's/^/MAC: /;x;s/.*//;N;s/\n/IP: /;G;s/\n/  /' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"." 'NF>4{m=$0}NF==4{print "IP:"$0" MAC:"m}' file
```